# MySQLdb placeholder implementation does not work

Tags: python, mysql

Python’s MySQLdb module should implement placeholders using format specifiers in the SQL statement string. I am following an exemple from the MYSQL CookBook

```
import sys
import MySQLdb
import Cookbook

try:
    conn = Cookbook.connect ()
    print("Connected")
except MySQLdb.Error as e:
    print("Cannot connect to server")
    print("Error code:", e.args[0])
    print("Error message:", e.args[1])
    sys.exit (1)

cursor = conn.cursor ()
cursor.execute (""" 
                INSERT INTO profile (name,birth,color,foods,cats)
                VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
                """,("Josef", "1971-01-01", None, "eggroll", 4))
```

But when I check from the shell

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM profile WHERE name LIKE  'J%';
+----+--------+------------+-------+----------------+------+
| id | name   | birth      | color | foods          | cats |
+----+--------+------------+-------+----------------+------+
|  7 | Joanna | 1952-08-20 | green | lutefisk,fadge |    0 |
+----+--------+------------+-------+----------------+------+
```

It is obvious that nothing is inserted.Why?
If I add cursor.commit as suggested

```
    cursor.commit()
AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'commit'
```

Comment: check the edited answer. change cursor to conn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not committing the transaction.

Add `conn.commit()` in the end after executing the query.

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute (""" 
            INSERT INTO profile (name,birth,color,foods,cats)
            VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
            """,("Josef", "1971-01-01", None, "eggroll", 4))
conn.commit()
```